# foreach loop with multiple logic conditions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach, asp.net-4.5

I have a collection of objects that I need to iterate through and do stuff with. Seems easy so far.  However, I have some conditions which is making it rather complicated.

**Here is some info:**

The collection contains a bunch of "Planet" objects which have planetary phase times.

Planetary viewing times are combined into blocks if the time span between 2 phases is less than or equal to 30 minutes.

**For example, here are 6 phase times:**

- Phase 1: 8:00am - 9:30am
- Phase 2: 10:00am - 11:00am
- Phase 3: 11:20am - 12:30pm
- Phase 4: 2:00pm - 4:00pm
- Phase 5: 6:30pm - 7:30pm
- Phase 6: 7:45pm - 9:00pm

With the data above, we have the following blocks:

- Phase 1 through Phase 3: one continuous viewing block
- Phase 4: separate viewing block
- Phase 5 and Phase 6: one continuuous viewing block

**Math:**

- (Phase 2 starting time) - (Phase 1 ending time) = 30 minutes
- (Phase 3 starting time) - (Phase 2 ending time) = 20 minutes
- (Phase 4 starting time) - (Phase 3 ending time) = 90 minutes
- (Phase 5 starting time) - (Phase 4 ending time) = 150 minutes
- (Phase 6 starting time) - (Phase 5 ending time) = 15 minutes

My failed attempt thus far:

```
int i = 0;
bool continueBlocking = false;

    foreach (var p in GalaxySector)  //IEnumerable
    {
        //ensure that dates are not null
        if (p.StartDatePhase != null || p.EndDatePhase != null) {

            if (continueBlocking) {
                string planetName = p.Name;
                string planetCatalogId = p.CatalogId;
                datetime? StartPhase = p.StartDatePhase.Value;
                datetime? EndPhase = p.EndDatePhase.Value;
            } else {
                string planetName = p.Name;
                string planetCatalogId = p.CatalogId;
                datetime? StartPhase = p.StartDatePhase.Value;
                datetime? EndPhase = p.EndDatePhase.Value;
            }

            if (i < 2) {
         continue;  
            }

            TimeSpan? spanBetweenSections = StartPhase - EndPhase;


    if ( spanBetweenSections.Value.TotalMinues <= 30) {
               continueBlocking = true; 
               continue;

            } else {

                CreateSchedule(planetName, planetCatalogId, StartPhase, EndPhase);
                continueBlocking = false;
            }


      }

     i++;

   }
```

I've spent hours on this stupid loop and I think another set of eyes would do it good.

It feels/looks too complex, too old-fashioned, and too confusing.  Is there a better/modern way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do phases circle back after midnight? In other words, do `12:15am - 2:30am` and `10:00pm - 11:50pm` constitute a single viewing?

Comment: If continueBlocking do X, else do X. X = X. So why are you using continueBlocking ?

Comment: have you looked into making case statements rather than the multiple if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping like that could be done very conveniently if you pack multiple loops into an enumerable-returning method with `yield return`:

```
private static readonly TimeSpan HalfHour = TimeSpan.Parse("0:30");

private static IEnumerable<Schedule> Group(IList<GalaxySector> all) {
    // Protect from division by zero
    if (all.Count == 0) {
        yield break;
    }
    // Find initial location
    var pos = 0;
    while (pos < all.Count) {
        var prior = (pos + all.Count - 1) % all.Count;
        if (all[prior].End+HalfHour >= all[pos].Begin) {
            pos++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Protect from wrap-around when all items belong to a single window
    pos = pos % all.Count;
    // Start grouping items together
    var stop = pos;
    do {
        var start = pos;
        var next = (pos+1) % all.Count;
        while (next != stop && all[pos].End+HalfHour >= all[next].Begin) {
            pos = next;
            next = (pos+1) % all.Count;
        }
        yield return new Schedule {Begin = all[start].Begin, End = all[pos].End};
        pos = next;
    } while (pos != stop);
}
```

The code above performs "wrap around" for midnight ([demo](http://ideone.com/xzqp45)).

The approach is relatively simple: first loop finds the location from which to start iterating by looking one step back, so that the schedule is continuous after wrap-around. The second loop remembers the starting position, and advances one step at a time, checking if the windows are closer than a half-hour apart. Once a big enough break is found, or when we reach the starting point again, the second loop stops.

If you would rather not use `yield return`, you could replace it with adding items to a `List<Schedule>`.

```
var all = new GalaxySector[] {
    new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("0:15"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("2:30")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("2:45"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("3:30")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("8:00"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("9:30")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("10:00"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("11:00")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("11:20"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("12:30")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("14:00"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("16:00")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("18:30"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("19:30")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("19:45"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("21:00")}
,   new GalaxySector {Begin=TimeSpan.Parse("22:00"), End=TimeSpan.Parse("23:50")}
};
foreach (var sched in Group(all)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}..{1}", sched.Begin, sched.End);
}
```

Output:

```
08:00:00..12:30:00
14:00:00..16:00:00
18:30:00..21:00:00
22:00:00..03:30:00
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, but using the code above, it cannot resolve the 'Begin' or 'End' symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those are dates and not just times of day you could do the following

```
var galaxySector = new List<PlanetPhase>
{
    new PlanetPhase
    {
        Name = "Saturn",
        StartDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 8, 0, 0),
        EndDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 9, 30, 0)
    },
    new PlanetPhase
    {
        Name = "Saturn",
        StartDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 10, 0, 0),
        EndDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 11, 0, 0)
    },
    new PlanetPhase
    {
        Name = "Saturn",
        StartDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 11, 20, 0),
        EndDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 12, 30, 0)
    },
    new PlanetPhase
    {
        Name = "Saturn",
        StartDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 14, 0, 0),
        EndDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 16, 0, 0)
    },
    new PlanetPhase
    {
        Name = "Saturn",
        StartDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 18, 30, 0),
        EndDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 19, 30, 0)
    },
    new PlanetPhase
    {
        Name = "Saturn",
        StartDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 19, 45, 0),
        EndDatePhase = new DateTime(2016, 7, 22, 21, 0, 0)
    },
};


PlanetPhase previous = null;
int groupon = 0;
var results = galaxySector.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        PlanetName = grp.Key,
        Phases = grp.OrderBy(p => p.StartDatePhase)
            .Select(p =>
            {
                if (previous != null
                    && p.StartDatePhase - previous.EndDatePhase > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
                {
                    groupon++;
                }

                previous = p;

                return new
                {
                    groupOn = groupon,
                    p.StartDatePhase,
                    p.EndDatePhase
                };
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.groupOn)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Start = g.Min(x => x.StartDatePhase),
                End = g.Max(x => x.EndDatePhase)
            })
            .ToList()
    });

foreach (var r in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.PlanetName);
    foreach (var p in r.Phases)
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{p.Start} - {p.End}");
}
```

That will output

> Saturn
>
> 7/22/2016 8:00:00 AM - 7/22/2016 12:30:00 PM
>
> 7/22/2016 2:00:00 PM - 7/22/2016 4:00:00 PM
>
> 7/22/2016 6:30:00 PM - 7/22/2016 9:00:00 PM